# Help Needed on derivates and functions including maximum and minimum points

Tags: functions, derivatives

How do I solve this question?

The function
$$f(x)=−4x^3−12x^2+96x+1$$

is increasing on the interval(s)

is decreasing on the interval (s)

The function has a local maximum at x is

How can I solve this? Do I find the derivates?

Comment: You need to show some work.

Comment: @OliviaJaneWilkinson: Plot the function and then see if you can work through the details and show this work. Regards

Comment: I am meant to do this without a calculator. It must be all hand written.

Comment: I think @Amzoti is suggesting that you plot it to get an idea of where these regions are so that you can easily prove statements about the regions themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Take the derivative of $f(x)$,
$$f'(x) = -12x^2-24x+96.$$
Where $f'(x)>0$ the function $f(x)$ is increasing.

Where $f'(x)<0$ the function $f(x)$ is decreasing.

To find the extrema (maximum/minimum) set $f'(x)=0$ and solve for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: To show a function is increasing or decreasing on an interval, the First Derivative Test is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Find first derivation $f'(x)$ then calculate $f'(s)$. If $f'(s) > 0$ then increasing if $f'(s)<0$ then decreasing .
To find local maximum [see this link](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-find-local-extrema-with-the-first-derivativ.html)